# How do I add my Mozilla Weave account's OpenID to my existing SO account?

Tags: support, openid, firefox, mozilla-weave

I tried using the "add openid" feature and then clicking on the "Sign In Using Weave" button that the add-on has, I get the chomping lizard page:

[chomping lizard http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/5771/mozchomp.gif](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/5771/mozchomp.gif)

...but then I get this error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> OpenID parameter 
>   'AGh0dHBzO[...big-string-continues-here...]='
>   was expected to be base64 encoded but is not.

I suspect it's a [Weave](http://labs.mozilla.com/weave/) issue since it's beta, but just wondering if there's a workaround for it.

Comment: Odd, I was thinking the "a little goto couldn't hurt..." comic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenId is Weave is being phased out and replaced by a separate plugin.

Here's the draft: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Identity/Account_Manager